# Implementing logging in mvc3 application is it possible to get signature for each action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, exception, controller

I have the following code (below), I am able to get controller and action. Is it possible to get signature(s) of each action?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                var loggingWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Items.Add(StopwatchKey, loggingWatch);

                var message = new StringBuilder();
                message.Append(string.Format("Executing controller: {0}, action: {1}, parameter: {2}",
                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName));

                log.Debug(message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dig into the actual value of the parameters you will need to use reflection.  To get name of the parameters and their types you can use the `filterContext`.

```
foreach (var actionParameter in filterContext.ActionParameters)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(actionParameter.Key + ", " + actionParameter.Value);
}
```

Failing that you can get method signature information using `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`.

For example:

```
foreach (var frame in new StackTrace().GetFrames())
{
    Trace.WriteLine(frame.GetMethod().Name);
}
```

Play around with it but it should give you what you need.